Running a self-certified PowerShell script without administrator rights?
I authenticated a .PS1 script with a self-issued certificate as an administrator, who can now himself run the script with ExecutionPolicy AllSigned.
However I could not find any way to authenticate this script or a newly written copy of it as a normal user (the error message is misleading: "the file has been modified").
I also copied the admin's certificate to the normal user with success (mmc export/import), but the normal user still can't run the script, nor use this certificate for any authentication.
Other solutions from the web didn't work either, for example a certificate moved to the root is also unusable (X509 error).
The only way seems to be setting ExecutionPolicy to Unrestricted… but thie is not really wanted.

If you want to run a script elevated you need to have administrative rights. It does not matter if the script is signed with a certificate or not. Execution policy has nothing to do with elevation.  ☝

it's always useful for you and the readers to have a list of the different approaches taken in order to prevent redundancy and encourage participation.

It had nothing to do with adm elevation, standard users could not start this script. By luck I had to reset the PC to a previous state (for an unrelated reason) using Win7 restore. Then it appeared that the .PS1 package (containing a certificate) had not been installed correctly the first time. Now standard users can start the script when the execution policy is AllSigned.
Wowever, this doesn't resolve the problem for future scripts which will be issued by the local administrator…
